# Why are my comments collapsed on YouTube

Tags: youtube, comments, youtube-channel

I am trying to advertise a YouTube channel by commenting below on trending videos.

When I log out and try to see these comments, there were no comments shown. I have checked completely and carefully. I have checked by using another ID too.

Are they hidden by default? what are possible solutions to this? can you explain please?

Answer (score 5):

You've been caught spamming!

Comments are supposed to be related to the video they are attached to, and advertising another channel is most likely irrelevant to the discussion.

Solution: save yourself some grief and time, spare others the nuisance of spam, and spend a few bucks in an actual, proper advertising solution.

(AdWords comes to mind, they'll even give you free credit to try it out and redeem you from the evil ways of comment spam)